# After save redirect to action "show"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I created an app where a Doctor can enter treatments for his patient. I added some validation and now when the doctor enters wrong things, Rails somehow redirects to the patient form and asks the user to change his input. But I don't want this behavior! When the input is false, Rails simply should not save it and redirect to patient show!!

Here is my controller:

```
def create
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
  @treatment = @patient.treatments.create(params[:treatment])
  redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
end
```

And my model:

```
class Treatment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :patient
  validates :content, presence: true
  ...
end
```

Comment: As per your specification, your code will work. Can you please share your view (new.html.erb) for the treatments controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by:

```
render action: 'show'
```

But if the patient is not created, how can we show it? You may want to use:

```
render action: 'new'
```

or

```
render action: 'index'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def create
  @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
  @treatment = @patient.treatments.new(params[:treatment])
  if @treatment.save
    redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
  else
    ## The page you want to redirect to
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok looks good but how can i define redirect_to patient_path(@patient) with action show?

Comment: the show action of which controller? The patient controller? If so patient_path(@patient) is already calling the show action of the patient controller.

Comment: if wrote: else redirect_to patient_path(@patient) And then if the input is wrong it redirects to patient edit! How can i change it to patient show?